# nodejs and SSL: how to specify the SSL in http.createServer creation?

Tags: node.js, ssl

I have found that snippet that works fine:

```
var ssl = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem')
};
var httpsServer = https.createServer(ssl).listen(port);
```

However my site uses that server construction:

```
var server = http.createServer(httpRequestsHandler).listen(_port_, function() {
    process.setgid('www-data');
    process.setuid('user1');
});
```

Question: how/where do I specify the ssl in this case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) your code has to look like this:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

var ssl = {
    key:  fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem')
};

var server = https.createServer(ssl, httpRequestsHandler).listen(_port_, function() {
    process.setgid('www-data');
    process.setuid('user1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you look at [this](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html) site